# what is the difference between preMel and preRender in Maya

Tags: python, maya, mel

in the [Maya Documentation](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-0280AB86-8ABE-4F75-B1B9-D5B7DBB7E25A-htm.html)  some flags are described

> -preFrame: MEL code executed before each frame.
>
> -preRender: MEL code executed before rendering.
>
> -preLayer: MEL code executed before each render layer.

and in the UI you have the option to specify `defaultRenderGlobals.preMel` in the render globals

my question being, is there a difference between the preMel that you specify in the UI or is it the same flag as -preFrame.

which one would I choose if I need to run something only once, say at the beginning of the job?

Answer (score 1):

If I read the docs correctly then the preMel (-pre flag) is deprecated and should not used any more even if it may work. So you should use the -preRender flag.